# Runtime C function details

Tags: c, function, parameters, runtime

Is there any way to find particular C language function's input and output parameters from a framework (apple's ARM) during the runtime or from any method with out knowing the headers.

It is a framework and there are no header files for it.I decompile it with IDA Pro and it gives me the function names but not input and output parameters information.

I am able to load those private functions using dlsym.

Is it possible to find the parameters info in runtime (C language or Objective C) or from IDA Pro ?

Regards,

Raghu

Comment: Does Google find nothing when you search names of these functions?

Comment: Why don't you have the headers - are you trying to do something illegal?
15 questions asked - no answers accepted. I think I'll move on.

Comment: Sridhar: That's not the point - marking the most helpful / correct solution as "accepted" will help the *next* person that has the question find the right answer.

Comment: Ok I will do that caf :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost impossible without debug information or something, i think. If there are some structs passed, or pointers, you won't be able to guess their meaning from disassembly, anyway (it could be possible to guess a few types, such as floats, but no more)

Comment: How about knowing while executing the program by passing function name or something ?

Comment: No idea, because function signatures in C bear no info about the parameters. I don't see any way to learn the parameters of the debug info is unavailable.